# Difference between homeomorphism and quotient map

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I am learning topology and would like to know the difference between 

[Homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism) and 
[Quotient maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Quotient_map). I will be grateful if anyone can help me in any way.

Comment: See [Is every homeomorphism a quotient map?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178873/is-every-homeomorphism-a-quotient-map)

Comment: Typically, quotient maps are not injective, because you want to use them when you *make a quotient* wrt an equivalence relation.

Comment: More precisely: if $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space, and $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$, the quotient topology on $X/\sim$ is defined in such a way that $\pi:X\to X/\sim$ is a quotient map.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli ok so quotient maps need not be injective but homeomorphisms have to be injective, correct?

Comment: It is not usual to do so, but actually a homeomorphism can be thought of as a quotient map having the special property of being injective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quotient maps could be not injective. However, when you have a quotient map $f:X\to Y$ then $f$ induces a homeomorphism between the quotient space $X/\sim_f$ and $Y$, where $x_1\sim_fx_2$ iff $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Note that this relation is trivial when $f$ is injective (therefore a homeomorphism) and in this case clearly $X/\sim_f\cong X$.